# How to control the displayed text of a ChipField in react-admin?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-admin, react-final-form

By default the `ChipField` can only show the content of a field, at least this is what the documentation tells. The example below displays the contents of the field `name`.

```
   <ReferenceArrayField source="substances" reference="substances" label="Substanzen">
      <SingleFieldList>
         <ChipField source="name" />
      </SingleFieldList>
   </ReferenceArrayField>
```

However, I want `ChipField` to display a text combined of information from several fields:

```
const Substanz = ({ record }) =>  {
    return record.name+" ("+record.unit+")";
};

<ReferenceArrayField source="substances" reference="substances" label="Substanzen">
   <SingleFieldList>
      <ChipField source={<Substanz />} />       <---- this does not work!
   </SingleFieldList>
</ReferenceArrayField>
```

but unfortunately, `source` only accepts a field name, not an object like the `OptionText` prop of  the `SelectInput` field.

What is the expected way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there with your custom `SubstanzField` component. Just use `MUI` styled component to make your own `ChipField`-like looking component and pass it directly inside of the `SingleFieldList`

[MUI Chips docs](https://material-ui.com/demos/chips/)

Don't know if you expected more sophisticated solution but this should be simple and flexible enough for your case.

Comment: Thanks, at the end I created a custom Component using ````Chip```` from ````material-ui```` which is the base for react-admins ````ChipField```` anyway.

Comment: U r welcome, that's my approach also with custom components most of the time.